# agm-circle Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Observable.subscribe

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, agm

Good afternoon, I am new to angular 8 and AGM maps, I am trying to generate a circle on the map but when I implement it I get the following

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Observable._subscribe (agm-core.js:292)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at agm-core.js:1499
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AgmCircle._registerEventListeners (agm-core.js:1498)
    at AgmCircle.ngOnInit (agm-core.js:1449)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31910)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
```

my code is the following

```
   <mat-card-content class="text-justify ">
     <agm-map [latitude]=" contri.latitude " [longitude]=" contri.longitude " [zoom]="mapzoom ">
          <agm-circle [latitude]="40.7127753"  [longitude]="-74.0059728"                     [clickable]="false"    [draggable]="true"   [editable]="false"   [fillColor]="green"                       [fillOpacity]="0"       [radius]="175.61"> </agm-circle>

                </agm-map>
            </mat-card-content>
```

in the app.module.js I have the following import

```
 imports: [ 
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzZZaassdqws4aaa',
      libraries: ["places", "geometry"]
    })
```

Someone has gotten this error or knows what it is due to

Comment: Hey @MRSDY SOTO,  Any luck on this issue? I am also stucked due to this.

Comment: Me too, same exact error. Only have [latitude],[longitude],[radius],[fillColor] bound on html, and they must be right, since circle is drawn correctly.

Comment: You can add some changes in the library itself, I am sharing a link where you can find what to change: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1871
I tried this and this works.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is a downgrade to "@agm/core": "1.1.0"

This worked for me

The actual version is 3.0.0 beta and its a Pre Release, so this means that is not a stable version

I took the example package.json from this plunker
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Check the releases
https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/releases